How to fix the Viber error "The procedure entry point IsWow64Process2 could not be located in the dynamic link library error in Viber"?
I got an error while opening the software Viber. It looks like this:

The error reads

"The procedure entry point IsWow64Process2 could not be located in the dynamic link library error in Viber"

I tried using the cmd command
sfc /scannow
to fix any error occured in Viber but to no avail.
I also tried to uninstall and reinstall the Viber program but the error persisted.
How could fix the error

"The procedure entry point IsWow64Process2 could not be located in the dynamic link library error in Viber"

Thanks for helping me out!

The IsWow64Process2 procedure appeared in Windows 10 starting with version 1709 and in Windows 11. It will not work on others. You need to uninstall Viber and install the version for Windows 8.1 and older from the site. Just did it, it helped.

It's true. I Installed the older version of Viber to fix the error. When I installed the older version of Viber on the desktop while having the latest version on Viber, nothing happens but the error goes away. Thanks!

I was encountering the same problem. I came up with a solution for this problem. All you gotta do is install (HxD - Freeware Hex Editor and Disk Editor) and boom. Your porblem will be solved. Thank you.

Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why it does so.
